# KMM - Unresolved reference: platform for IOS application

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, mobile, kmm

Hellow.
I have a trouble with template **KMM** application. It got an error after I created new KMM application - in shared IOS app module it cannot find package **platform**. It's on kotlin. Adroid app works well.

Need to say, that I works on window by Android studio. I know there are troubles to start IOS app on window, but I do not want to start or build app - I want to just it find the reference **platform**.

I tried to find some dicisions. There are the same questions, but nobody can answer them.

Code with trouble:

```
import platform.UIKit.UIDevice // here there is the error

actual class Platform actual constructor() {
    actual val platform: String = UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() + " " + UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit strange: how do you think iOS application will compile and work on a Windows computer?

To make KMM work on both OS you need a Mac. This is the reason why you are not able to find "platform.UIKit.UIDevice" on your machine.

Comment: Thank you very much! But there are nothing strange in my question. For me - I can use any kotlin package if I have JVM with needed version. I do not know what is inside that package just by name. As I understood it is not just kotlin package, so JVM is not enough.

Comment: Sorry for my message, I apologize if it was too strong. But even if KMM lets you manage both iOS and Android applications from Android Studio, the main point is that iOS applications must be compiled, runned or tested on a Mac machine.